# Access VSTS on UWP

Tags: uwp

Is there an easy API to access Visual Studio Team Service account on UWP app? I remembered seeing some app on the store doing this but it might be taken down. I know it is impossible with the current [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/get-started/auth/oauth). It should be possible if I make a proxy web app though I would like an easier approach. On the other hand, is there an easy way to replicate the functionality of VSTS on my own server? It would be great to do that on an Raspberry PI for compilation and automated testing.

Comment: As I know there is no easy API to access Visual Studio Team Service account on UWP app. Also what functionality of VSTS do you want to replicate?

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT I want to replicate the web service. I want to build a personal server that I can initiate building and releasing from my mobile device.